# How to build swig on ubuntu?

Tags: 16.04, compiling, cmake

I am trying to install swig on ubuntu 16.04 as it is required for building opencv for android. I found a guide to do this:

```
git clone https://github.com/swig/swig.git

cd swig
./autogen.sh
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

But i'm getting the error when i type 5th command `make` in the current directory.

```
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/mctrjalloh/swig/Source'
/bin/bash ../Tools/config/ylwrap CParse/parser.y y.tab.c CParse/parser.c y.tab.h `echo CParse/parser.c | sed -e s/cc$/hh/ -e s/cpp$/hpp/ -e s/cxx$/hxx/ -e s/c++$/h++/ -e s/c$/h/` y.output CParse/parser.output -- yacc -d 
../Tools/config/ylwrap: line 176: yacc: command not found
Makefile:962: recipe for target 'CParse/parser.c' failed
make[1]: *** [CParse/parser.c] Error 127
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/mctrjalloh/swig/Source'
Makefile:37: recipe for target 'source' failed
make: *** [source] Error 2
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: *yacc: command not found* `yacc` is provided by the `bison` package. But isn't `swig` already available from the universe repository?

Comment: @steeldriver i don't get what you mean?

Comment: I mean, why are you building swig from source, when it's available from the repo? that's usually only necessary if you need a more recent version for example

Comment: @steeldriver it was complaining about it when building opencv

Comment: @steeldriver it was complaining about it when building opencv

Answer (score 3):

Actually the yacc command was not installed so i ran:

```
sudo apt-get install bison flex
```

and i works!

Credits to @steeldriver for hint in a comment to the question.